# ¿Como hacer que una pelota choque y cree mas pelotas?

Tags: java, poo, jframe

antes que nada estoy aprendiendo a programar en java y nos dejaron en clase hacer que al rebotar una pelota en el borde de la pantalla, esta creara una pelota adicional y así exponencialmente, Ya lo tengo funcionando pero al iniciar en vez de ser solo una pelota se crean dos y una de ellas se queda en la esquina de la pantalla sin ningún movimiento, no he podido detectar porque sea y no he encontrado solución a esto, mis clases son Pelota y juego

**Clase pelota**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class Pelota {

// ver posicion de la pelota
private int posicionX[] = new int[10];
private int posicionY[] = new int[10];

// controlar la direccion del movimiento
private int movimientoX[] = new int[10];
private int movimientoY[] = new int[10];

// Lugar utilizado para colocar la pelota
private Juego juego;
// tamaño de la pelota
private static final int TAMAÑO_PELOTA = 15;

public Pelota(int i, Juego juego) {
    this.juego = juego;
    movimientoX[i] = 1;
    movimientoY[i] = 1;
    posicionX[i] = new Random().nextInt(200);
    posicionY[i] = new Random().nextInt(100);

}

/**
 * Permite mover la pelota y rebotarla en las paredes
 */
public void mover() {


    // MOvimiento X
   for(int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            if (posicionX[i] + movimientoX[i] < 0) {
                movimientoX[i] = 1;
               Juego.pelotas.add(new Pelota(i,this.juego));
            }else
            if (posicionX[i] + movimientoX[i] > juego.getWidth() - TAMAÑO_PELOTA) {
                movimientoX[i] = -1;
                Juego.pelotas.add(new Pelota(i,this.juego));
            }else
            // Movimento Y
            if (posicionY[i] + movimientoY[i] < 0) {
                movimientoY[i] = 1;
                Juego.pelotas.add(new Pelota(i,this.juego));
            }else
            if (posicionY[i] + movimientoY[i] > juego.getHeight() - TAMAÑO_PELOTA) {
                movimientoY[i] = -1;
                Juego.pelotas.add(new Pelota(i,this.juego));
            }

            posicionX[i] += movimientoX[i];
            posicionY[i] += movimientoY[i];

   }   
}
public void visualizar(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
        g.fillOval(posicionX[i], posicionY[i], TAMAÑO_PELOTA, TAMAÑO_PELOTA);

    }
}

}
```

**Clase Juego**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Juego extends JPanel{

static ArrayList<Pelota> pelotas = new ArrayList(15);



public Juego() {
        pelotas.add(new Pelota(0,Juego.this));

}

public void moverPelota() {
    for(int i=0; i<pelotas.size();i++) {
        ((Pelota) pelotas.get(i)).mover();
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    for(int i=0; i<pelotas.size();i++) {
        ((Pelota) pelotas.get(i)).visualizar(g2d);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Pelota rebotando");
    Juego juego = new Juego();
    jFrame.add(juego);
    jFrame.setSize(300, 400);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while (true) {
        juego.moverPelota();
        juego.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(6);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la clase `Pelota` no tengo clara la razón de ser del valor 10 en el ciclo `for` del método `mover` y del método `visualizar`, de todas maneras hay dos cosas:

1. **Indices**:

Dentro de `visualizar` sirve apuntar solamente a la primera posición de los arrays en vez de hacer uso del ciclo y recorrer, ya que de algún modo repintará la pelota que queda 'inmóvil':

```
public void visualizar(Graphics2D g) {
  g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  g.fillOval(posicionX[0], posicionY[0], TAMAÑO_PELOTA, TAMAÑO_PELOTA);

  /*for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
    g.fillOval(posicionX[i], posicionY[i], TAMAÑO_PELOTA, TAMAÑO_PELOTA);
  }*/
}
```

2. **Tamaño de Arrays**:

Importante; hay que tener bastante cuidado a la hora de implementar dichas estructuras de ese modo, por ejemplo, al simplemente hacer crecer de manera ***exponencialmente indefinida*** el `ArrayList` `pelotas` va a ocasionar que la aplicación falle y/o que peor aun cuelgue el ordenador por completo, todo es cuestión de consumo de recursos.

Lo que se recomienda para ese caso es hacer el llamado [Double Buffering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html).